# SOQL Query Parent to child

Tags: soql

I have three object tour, tour visit and Tour Suit . In that Tour is the Parent of Tour Visit and then Tour Visit is the parent of Tour Suit, So in Tour suit there is field Call property Name , I want to retrieve the data from Tour Object Is it possible to Retrieve the Property Name through Tour Object because there is no relationship between tour and tour suit , How we can write soql query for it.

Answer (score 2):

Given the information you've provided, no, it is not possible to query the `Property Name` from your `Tour_Suit__c` object (is that perhaps supposed to be Tour *Suite*?) when the query is based around the `Tour__c` object.

SOQL only allows us to query one level down a hierarchy (from Parent to Child), and you would need to query down *two* levels.

We can, however, query up to 5 levels *upwards* in a hierarchy. So if your query is based on `Tour_Suit__c`, you could query information about the `Tour__c`.

Something like `SELECT Tour_Visit__r.Tour__r.Name FROM Tour_Suit__c WHERE Tour_Visit__r.Tour__c IN :tourIdList`